# Access another Base Classes member from Abstract Base Class

Tags: c++

I wonder if it is possible to declare a pure virtual function in class `AbstractBase` and make a `Base` classes member visible in `Derived` so it will use the member of `Base` and not look for a implementation in `Derived`. So far, i tried making `Base`'s member visual by trying to use `using` but it won't compile since the look up, in this case, seems to ignore using. Is this possible at all? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class AbstractBase {

public:
    AbstractBase(){}
    virtual ~AbstractBase(){}

protected:
    virtual void f() = 0;


};

class Base {

public:
    Base(){}

protected:
    void f() {cout << "called Base's f()" << endl;}

};

class Derived : public Base, public AbstractBase {

public:
    Derived(){}
    //using Base::f; /*this won't compile*/
private:
    void f(){} /*Access Base's f() here rather than implement*/


};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `::` operator:

```
class Derived : public Base {

public:
    Derived(){}
private:
    void f(){ Base::f() }  
};
```

Also, you don't need to inherit from `AbstractBase`.

Comment: As simple as that. It is a simplified case. This gets useful when using `Derived` again as `AbstractBase`. Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanMee So what is it? To me it's also known as `namespace operator`.

Comment: It is according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#C.2B.2B)

Comment: @tobilocker if I answered the question, please mark the answer as solution :)

Comment: @tobilocker I stand corrected. I had never heard it called an operator. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you would like `f()` to be pure-virtual but provide default implementation. In this case, it can be achieved this way:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct AbstractBaseWithDefaultF 
{
    virtual ~AbstractBaseWithDefaultF() = default;
    virtual void f() = 0;
};
void AbstractBaseWithDefaultF::f()
{
    cout << "called AbstractBaseWithDefaultF's f()" << endl;
}

struct Derived : AbstractBaseWithDefaultF
{
    void f() override 
    {
        AbstractBaseWithDefaultF::f();
        cout << "called Derived's f()" << endl;
    } 
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.f();
}
```

Output:

```
called AbstractBaseWithDefaultF's f()
called Derived's f()
```

Here's a [live Wandbox example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aj02glIBz1QEGIZP).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, sure. Corrected. Speed-answering adrenalin-rush is to blame :)